# Showing a grammar is ambiguous

Tags: compiler, parsing, grammar, ambiguity

I have the following question taken from a compilers course exam:

```
Show that the following grammar is ambiguous.

S = XcY
X = a
Y = b | Z
Z = bW
W = d | ϵ
```

I drew the following tree:

[image: grammar diagram]

Am I correct in thinking it is ambiguous because **acY** can end up at **acb** (one of which is followed by an epslion) following different paths?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Since epsilon means you can rewrite W as the empty string, acbW -> acb. As you have shown, there are two leftmost derivations for the string acb, which [by definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambiguous_grammar) means the grammar is ambiguous.